# Line-height affects images?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/xJmZt/

As you can see in the above example , there is extra height of about 6px on the `div`.

That extra height is gone if line-height is changed to ~1px ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/xJmZt/1/)).

So line-height affects images too ?

Comment: @Matt Ball I thought line-height only affects text :/  . @Matteo Riva
's answer makes it clear .

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940338/is-there-a-way-via-css-to-set-the-image-height-to-the-line-height

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Images by default are defined as inline elements so they follow text rules, you can either set the container height to match the images', or give the image `display: block` or `vertical-align: bottom`.