# I wanna remove white space between elements html/css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im developing this website by using wordpress and the client requested a custom bar( www.orbit.yetu.co.tz ) But once i inserted the image and created a div for it, it automatically generated a white space between itself and the navigation bar.

```
    <body <?php body_class($body_classes); ?>>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- Main Container -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<div class="main-container">

    <!-- This is a custom bar added by me -->
    <div id="main-topbar">
    <img src="http://orbit.yetu.co.tz/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/top-bar-new.jpg" alt="Orbit Securities" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:1180px;height:90px">
    </div>
    <!--This is the end of the top bar -->

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <!-- Top Bar - Set "white" or "dark" below -->
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <div class="header <?php echo $basix_options['top_bar_style'] ?><?php if ($basix_options['fixed_header'] != FALSE) { ?> sticky<?php } ?>">
        <div class="topbar content-width">

            <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
            <!-- Logo -->
            <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to the `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

I check your code, and first of all, i would suggest to add a class to the image, to better handle with CSS.

To fix the error, apply the `display: block;` property to it, to get rid of the [line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664460/line-height-affects-images), in fact images by default are defined as inline elements so they follow text rules.

See here a live example [of the difference between inline and block](http://jsbin.com/dapube/1/) property apply to images.

And have a look [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/) to better understand the theory behind the difference.